# HTML5, CSS3 flex box not working properly

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I've learned that display flex help me reduce working hours for publishing.
However I've got a problem that the layout didn't display what I want.

All I want to display like grid layout like below :

[image]

But unfortunately I cannot fix this issue by myself.
Could you give me an advice how can I fix this issue with flex tag?

You can see my problem like below too :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
.item_wrap {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-flow: row-wrap;
}

.item_0 {
   width: 500px; 
   height: 500px; 
   background: #ff0;
}

.item_1 {
   width: 490px; 
   height: 160px; 
   background: #00f;
}

.item_2 {
   width: 240px; 
   height: 160px; 
   background: #ff00e4;
}

.item_3 {
   width: 240px; 
   height: 160px; 
   background: #ff00e4;
}

.item_4 {
   width: 240px; 
   height: 160px; 
   background: #1cc600;
}

.item_5 {
   width: 240px; 
   height: 160px; 
   background: #1cc600;
}
```

Comment: can you share in fiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change `HTML` structure.

All blocks on the right side should be wrapped in a `<div>`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item-wrap">
  <div class="item_0">0</div>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="item_1">1</div>
    <div class="item_2">2</div>
    <div class="item_3">3</div>
    <div class="item_4">4</div>
    <div class="item_5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item-wrap {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
.inner-wrap {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
.item_0,
.inner-wrap {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 5px);
}
.inner-wrap > div {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 5px);
}
.inner-wrap > .item_1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.item-wrap {
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.inner-wrap {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
.item_0,
.inner-wrap {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 5px);
}
.inner-wrap > div {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 5px);
  padding: 10px;
}
.inner-wrap > div + div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.inner-wrap > .item_1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.item_0{background:#ff0; padding: 10px;}
.item_1{background:#00f;}
.item_2{background:#ff00e4;}
.item_3{background:#ff00e4;}
.item_4{background:#1cc600;}
.item_5{background:#1cc600;}
```

```html
<div class="item-wrap">
  <div class="item_0">0</div>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="item_1">1</div>
    <div class="item_2">2</div>
    <div class="item_3">3</div>
    <div class="item_4">4</div>
    <div class="item_5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The only way to resolve my trouble is that changing HTML structure :(

Comment: @Richard you are welcome)

Answer (score 1):

## Hi! Please checkout this code

> HTML5, CSS3

```css
.item_wrap {
            width: 800px;
            display: flex;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .item_0 {
            height: 500px;
            background: red;
            flex: 1;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .item_1 {
            height: 500px;
            background: yellow;
            flex: 1;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .headbar {
        }

        .head_column {
            height: 200px;
            background: green;
            flex: 1;

        }

        .headbar2 {
            display: flex;
        }

        .pinkone {
            background: #000;
            flex: 1;
            height: 150px;
        }

        .pinktwo {
            background: pink;
            flex: 1;
            height: 150px;

        }

        .headbar3 {
            display: flex;
        }

        .grayone {
            background: gray;
            flex: 1;
            height: 150px;
        }

        .graytwo {
            background: blue;
            flex: 1;
            height: 150px;

        }
```

```html
<div class="item_wrap">
    <div class="item_0"></div>
    <div class="item_1">
        <div class="headbar">
            <div class="head_column"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="headbar2">
            <div class="pinkone"></div>
            <div class="pinktwo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="headbar3">
            <div class="grayone"></div>
            <div class="graytwo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Moreover you can follow YouTube Channel- [LearnWebCode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

Comment: Thank you very much. You are my angel :)

Comment: Welcome -@Richard